# xubuntu 22.04 How to make workspaces span multiple displays

Tags: gnome, xubuntu, multiple-monitors, workspaces

I have 3 displays and I want my current workspace to span all of them so that when I switch work spaces all 3 displays will switch to a new workspace.

As you probably know, the default is that you can only switch work spaces on your primary display.

I have read many posts on how to do this and their explanations are simple and easy to follow. The only problem is that in my case none of them work.

For example:

When I run the settings app ( setting from the main menu ) I have no multitasking option ( not even if I use the search feature. )

When I install gnome-tweaks, I have no work spaces option. My last available option is "Windows". Work spaces is supposed to be the next one down. It's not there.

When I poke around in workspace options, I find nothing useful.

When I search around in Dconf for things like "work space", "dynamic" and "Display" I find nothing helpful.

Is there some major difference between Xubuntu 22.04 and Ubuntu 22.04? I need to figure out how to get this working.

Comment: I'm lost by your description; the default behavior of GNOME & Ubuntu Desktop is when you switch workspace, only the primary display changes; HOWEVER the default of Xubuntu and Xfce is that when you change workspace all displays change.  Behavior differs between Xubuntu (Xfce) and Ubuntu Desktop (GNOME)

Comment: The *big* difference (*if it wasn't obvious in my prior comment*) in they are different DESKTOPs, using different WMs etc, thus of course experience differs. I'm using LXQt (Lubuntu session) currently, but on this box I have all of Ubuntu Desktop (GNOME) and Xubuntu (Xfce) installed with my selecting which I'll use when I login.  The Lubuntu session (LXQt) acts just like Xfce (*in fact I'm using `xfwm4` as my WM instead of Lubuntu's `openbox` for reasons*) but if I login with a GNOME session I'll get the opposite behavior you mention which is the default GNOME experience.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for my confusion. I was busy researching how to fix many issues and didn't notice that it was in fact working.

I also learned something new about xubuntu vs ubuntu. Thanks for that too! :-)

Comment: This is just FYI, but Xubuntu being a [flavor of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) is a Ubuntu system, just built using a different *seed* file which causes different packages found on the ISO thus what you get installed. This [link](https://ubuntu-archive-team.ubuntu.com/seeds/ubuntu.jammy/desktop) shows the *seed* of what is included on a Ubuntu Desktop ISO, where as this [link](https://ubuntu-archive-team.ubuntu.com/seeds/xubuntu.jammy/desktop) shows Xubuntu Desktop ISO; both being *jammy* or 22.04. The different desktop etc means a different GUI & thus behavior, we have choice!